# Void function return value is used JavaScript

Tags: javascript, html

```js
let btn = document.createElement("button");
btn.id = "submitBV"
let firstRow = 12
let lastRow = 59
btn.addEventListener("click", autoInput(firstRow, lastRow))

function autoInput(firstRow, lastRow){
    print()
}
```

It tells me `Void function return value is used` ([screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/0HVYK.png)).

After I add a `return 1`, it doesn't solve as well ([screenshot2](https://i.stack.imgur.com/pnHaU.png)).

Comment: [`.addEventListener()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/EventTarget/addEventListener) expects a callback function as its second argument. You're currently invoking `autoInput()`, thus passing its return value to `.addEventListener()`. You can pass an [anonymous function](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Functions#the_function_expression_function_expression) which invokes `autoInput()` instead, `btn.addEventListener("click", () => autoInput(firstRow, lastRow))`.

Comment: Or do `autoInput.bind(null, firstRow, lastRow)`.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Yes, because you are invoking the `autoInput` function which does not return something (`void`) valid. To handle this, to need to pass a function in order to be called when the `click` event is triggered by the button. In this case, you can add a simple function to do this.

```js
btn.addEventListener("click", function() { autoInput(firstRow, lastRow); })
```

If you have a function which returns another function (if you are new to javascript, yes, it is possible) it may work fine, which is not your case on the `autoInput` function.